# unble to attach Azure network security group with NIC with count value using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, virtual-network-interface

I Have written below code to attach security group with network interface using terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "attach_Nic_Nsg" {
     count                     = 2
     network_interface_id      = "${azurerm_network_interface.network_interface[count.index].id}"
     network_security_group_id = module.security_group.security_group_id
}
```

When i am executing terraform plan i am getting below error.

[image]

How to attach network security group for multiple Nic?

Answer (score 1):

Below Snippet solved my issue.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "attach_Nic_Nsg" {
    count                     = 2
    network_interface_id      = element(azurerm_network_interface.network_interface.*.id, count.index)
    network_security_group_id = module.security_group.security_group_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "attach_Nic_Nsg" {
network_interface_id = azurerm_network_interface.testnic.id
network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.testnsg.id }

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are some guides to help you [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make it more readable, and it is always helpful to provide some context in your answers - check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)